# Factor dependent correlation

Tags: correlation

If I take a set of measurements and test correlation of variable $A$ vs variable $B$ and get a significant correlation, that makes sense to me.  But what if further analysis reveals that of those factors, there is only a significant positive correlation within one group, and that group is over-represented.  Is the global correlation still valid, or is it, upon more detailed inspection a sample-bias effect?

Here is some graphs to explain:

The global correlation

[image: global correlation]

The group separated correlations

[image: grouping separated correlation]

Comment: Just a little comment: it looks like the overall correlation might partly be explained by the fact that units belonging to group A all have lower scores whereas considering `valueB` alone doesn't help to separate the three groups.

Comment: I think if you give us more content (i.e., what do the groups mean) you will get better advice on what to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I agree with JMS advice, that the answer is totally context dependent.

But what you are looking at may also be considered a [moderation effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moderation_%28statistics%29).

> In statistics, moderation occurs when
>   the relationship between two variables
>   depends on a third variable.

(quoted from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moderation_%28statistics%29))

A moderation is statistically significant if in a multiple regression analyses the interaction of the predictor with the third variable is significant.

Answer (score 8):

Are you familiar with [Simpson's paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_paradox)? This would seem to be what you're observing here.

Edit: I didn't answer your question :) What exactly you should do is to some degree context dependent (Are the groups meaningful? Does this represent a problem in the study design? etc). At the very least you should report both results IMO.

Answer (score 5):

The previous comments are all good, but with group sample sizes of 5, 7, and 11, I wouldn't trust any of their correlations as far as I could throw them.  You'll need to give the overall *r* a wide confidence interval as well.  btw Nice job on the graph.

Comment: +1, good point. I took it as an example, not the actual data, but reading again the OP certainly didn't say that.